# "Semi-complex" integral of function 1/(x-i)-1/(x+i).

Tags: integration, complex-integration

How can I calculate this$\int_{0}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{x-i}-\frac{1}{x+i})dx$? $x \in \Re$

If we considered $i$ just like a real constant, we would get the following(Considering that the integrand is "positive" - $\Re(x+i)>0$ and $\Re(x-i)>0$) : $Ln\frac{x-i}{x+i}|_{0}^{+\infty} = ln|1|-ln|1|+i[arg(1)-arg(-1) + 2\pi k] =i(\pi k+2\pi k)$
But...the last calculations are kind of strange, because we have an addend $2\pi k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the fractions to get
$$2i\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x=2i\left[\arctan{(x)}\right]_0^\infty=2i\left(\frac\pi2-0\right)=\pi i$$

Comment: Thank you, but my calculations are correct?)I have a more complicated integral, and I need to use the method I've described in general.

Comment: I have no idea what you did. As $x\to\infty$ you just get $\ln{(1)}=0$ and when $x=0$ you get $\ln{(-1)}=i\pi$. So your method gives the integral as $-i\pi$ which is incorrect. The integral only has one possible solution and that is $\pi i$. The problem stems from using the multi-valued complex logarithm.